# Binary map in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Is there a two-operand equivalent to `map` built into Haskell with a type signature of:

```
map2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
```

The following equivalence should hold:

```
map2 operator as bs === [operator a b | (a, b) <- zip as bs]
```

**Example:**

```
ghci> map2 (*) [2,3] [4,5]
[8,15]
```

Comment: You should use Hoogle for things like this, http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/ e.g. search for `(a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]` and you can even put this in your ghci.conf `:def hoogle \str -> return $ ":! hoogle --count=15 \"" ++ str ++ "\""` and then you can do `:hoogle foo` from ghci (after installing hoogle of course)

Comment: +1 I am a great fan of Hoogle.

Comment: For once, there's a reason asking people may be better than using Hoogle; you wouldn't find [align](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/these-0.3/docs/Data-Align.html#v:align) through Hoogle!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called `zipWith`.

Here's its type:
`zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]`

Example:

```
zipWith (*) [2,3] [4,5]
```

Produces:

```
[8,15]
```

I might also recommend that you take a look at Hoogle for such questions in the future. A [search for "(a->a->a)->[a]->[a]->[a]"](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a-%3Ea-%3Ea%29-%3E%5Ba%5D-%3E%5Ba%5D-%3E%5Ba%5D) turns up what you were looking for. :)

Answer (score 9):

The function [zipWith](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v%3azipWith) does what you need. There are also `zipWith3` .. `zipWith7` for cases with more than two lists.

Comment: Also note that the special case `zipWith (,)` is just `zip`.

Answer (score 1):

A more general solution is to use the `ZipList` instance of `Applicative` for lists:

```
let z = (+) <$> ZipList [2,3] <*> ZipList [4,5]
 in runZipList z
```

The nice thing here is that it works with operators of arbitrary arity, so instead of `zipWith3` .. `zipWith7`, you just tack on one more `<*> e`